# Instruct Google+ what image it should pick

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, google-plus

I have a project made in Wordpress.
I have posts which I share in social networks.
In twitter there is no problem, because I create tweets without image.
Facebook allows me to select the image of the page from the link I'm going to share.
But Google+ is picking up a random image, and does not allow me to select the image.

I've investigated in Google, and seems to work using something like this in the page which Im going to share:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Although Google+ sometimes supports the og:image property, it doesn't always.

Using a schema.org microdata "snippet" is the preferred way to do this for Google Search and Google+. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/ for more details and links to a testing tool which can tell you how your page is being read.

Additionally, for both og and snippet data, the image selected needs to be large enough and square enough. The height must be at least 120px, and if the width is less than 100px, then the aspect ratio must be no greater than 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read about it, and you're right. My image is like this: http://prntscr.com/4hkjo3 .....its dimensions are 269 x 157 ...... I think it meet with google requirements......